# Does the Toyota 2000 Camry LE have a cabin filter?

Tags: toyota, camry, cabin-filter

I know it has an air filter for the engine, but I'm not able to find where the cabin filter is, if there is one.

-The glove box can't be taken out.

-I'm not seeing anything when I remove the velcro upholstery near the floor mats.

I tried various web searches and the Toyota.com website downloadable PDF, but its still not clear; it just mentions 'Air filters' very vaguely which seem to be for the engine.

http://www.toyota.com/toyota-owners-online-theme/pdf/AirFilters2011-LowRes.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does, It's called the Interior Ventilation Filter. It's inside the glove box behind it. It's on 1999 and Later modols and can be found in Haynes and Chilton books for how to information.

Answer (score 5):

Checking several sites I have not found any thing that relates to a cabin air filter for your Camry. They list several other models but none for a Camry. For future reference Fram has a database that lists instructions for replacing cabin air filters by make ,model and year. It appears that they became available on the 2002 models.

Comment: It also varies wildly by market. In South Africa, for instance, The Opel Corsa B and C (known as a Buick Sail in the US and a Vauxhall Corsa in the UK) doesn't have the actual filter installed, althought the empty container smiles at you from behind the firewall.

Comment: Checking on a reliable auto parts site, it doesn't show a cabin air filter as being available for the 2000 Camry. Just confirming what @mikes is saying.

Comment: 2002 is the 5th generation of the Camry line, and is in fact when the cabin air filter was introduced to this model.